# UISplitViewController - getting a reference to the popover controller

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

My app has a `UISplitViewController` that initiates with the master view hidden.
Unless I rotate the device, the following delegate method

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
     willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
          withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
       forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc {
  _masterPopover = pc;
}
```

will never be invoked. And this is the only way I know to get a reference to the popover controller (the `pc` in that method).

I need the reference to able to programmatically show and hide the master popover, but I cannot depend on the users to rotate their iPads.
Is there any other way to get that reference?

Answer (score 1):

If the master view is hidden, then `willHideViewController` *must* be called. And when it is, you are handed the `barButtonItem` that lets the user summon the popover (and you stick it into your interface).

If that isn't working for you, my best advice is not to use UISplitViewController. Just roll your own. UISplitViewController has always been extremely poor (and you have put your finger directly on one of its main weaknesses), but since iOS 5 there has been a legal coherent way to write your own parent container controllers. So I would suggest you just do that.